# TransactionScope class equivalent in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, .net, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

What would be a somewhat equivalent class for TransactionScope(.Net) in Spring.

Comment: `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)`

Answer (score 2):

I know absolutely nothing about .Net, so I'm not certain if this is what you're looking for. You can use [`SimpleTransactionScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/SimpleTransactionScope.html) in order to maintain objects across the lifecycle of a transaction. It is not registered by default, so you will have to register it with spring core like any custom scope, and give it a stringy name. Then if you want you can also create an annotation specifically to register one.

It was my issue that suggested this a few years ago, after this question was created for certain. We requested it specifically for timestamps across multiple methods for injection in a service. You can do something like this.

```java
public class SimpleTransactionFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {
        factory.registerScope("transaction", new SimpleTransactionScope());
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {

    @Scope(scopeName = "transaction")
    @Bean
    Instant nowInstant() {
       return Instant.now();
    }

}
```

```
@Service
class MyService {

    private final ObjectFactory<Instant> nowFactory;

    MyService( @Qualifier("nowInstant") ObjectFactory<Instant> nowFactory ) {
       this.nowFactory = nowfactory
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean nowisEqualAlways() {
       var now = nowFactory.getObject();
       var sameNow = nowFactory.getObject();
       return Objects.equals( now, sameNow );
    }
}
```

If you don't do this, your `now` could actually change during your transaction by a small amount of time. You can test that simply by spamming now calls in a test.

It may not be required for your needs, so it's hard for me to tell (obviously your needs are probably long past, hopeful.y this helps someone in the future though)

Answer (score 0):

The [@Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/) annotation looks equivalent.

This can be placed on classes and methods and can be defined with propagation, isolation, rollback etc.